# XDocReport : XDocConverterException: Cannot find converters from=ODT

Tags: java, xdocreport

I'm trying to use the XDocReport for inject ODT and convert it to PDF, here is my java code :

```
InputStream in= new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\exemple.odt"));
                IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);

IContext context = report.createContext();
context.put("bean", "myMonthReport2016");

Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("exemple_Out.odt"));
report.convert(context, options, out);
```

The version used 1.0.6, my dependencies in pom.xml :

```
<!-- XDocReport -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
                <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core</artifactId>
                <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
                <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document</artifactId>
                <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
                <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template</artifactId>
<version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
                <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter</artifactId>
                <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
                <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.odt</artifactId>
                <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
                <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.odt.odfdom</artifactId>
                <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.odftoolkit.odfdom.converter</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.8</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
              <artifactId>odfdom-java</artifactId>
              <version>0.8.7</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>           <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity</artifactId>
                <version>${xdocreport.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Velocity -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

I got this error after test :

```
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.XDocConverterException: Cannot find converters from=ODT
```

I've followed this issue, but the error doesn't resolved
Issue : https://github.com/ricochango1/xdocreport/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution is to change the version of xdocreport as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

In the other side try something like this:

```
URL url = new File("D:\\exemple.odt").toURI().toURL();
InputStream documentAsStream = url.openStream();
IXDocReport xdocReport = ocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(inputStream, templateEngine);
```